# writing a static method to set counter java?

Tags: java, methods, static

I am pretty new to coding, I want to write a static method to set a count value to 1000.

I tried doing things like

```
public static  int setCounter(){
        return 1000;

    }
```

When try to use this method in another to increment the count

such as someVariable = symbolic constant + setCounter()++;
return someVariable, it gives me an unexpected type error, required variable, found value. What am i doing wrong?

edit*

edit*

```
private String getTicketNumber(){
    ticketNumber = TICKET_PREFIX + resetCounter()++;
    return ticketNumber;

 public static int resetCounter(int counter){
        counter = 1000;

    }
```

i want to call this counter to increment it in another method

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: noted. Will add everything in the future, sorry if I wasn't clear enough before

Comment: For sure, its all a learning process! Learning to ask great questions is a niche skill in and of itself. The part of this question that smells a bit funky is that, generally speaking, keeping state in a static (i.e. singleton) is bad practice. They do have their place, but it's often used as a last resort. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/138012/3280538

Comment: I totally agree with you there, Its for an intro programming class. I had earlier declared the counter as a symbolic constant in the beginning and then incremented it in my getTicketNumber method, it worked but reading the question again, Im asked to make it a static method to set the value to 1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An static property is associated with the definition of the class, and there is only ever one definition of the class. An instance is created whenever you use the `new` keyword on the class. All instances are keep their own private data from the static class. When using a class instance you can access the static variables but not the other way around.

You use the term constant, but I think you might have a bit of a misunderstanding of what that implies. Constants are often declared as `static` `final` values that are immutable (they can never be changed). You should not be able to modify a constant. A static value can be mutable if you so desire, and this is what we would sometimes refer to as a stateful singleton.

Consider these two examples... one modifies an instance variable, the other a static variable.

```
class InstanceFoo {
    int i = 1000;
    int resetCounter() {
        i = 1000;
        return i;
    }
    int getAndIncrement() {
        return i++;
    }
}

class StaticFoo {
    static int i = 1000;
    static int resetCounter() {
        i = 1000;
        return i;
    }
    static int getAndIncrement() {
        return i++;
    }
}
```

In the first example you need to use an instance to access the variables.. i.e. you need to instantiate it with `new`:

```
InstanceFoo foo = new InstanceFoo();
System.out.println(foo.resetCounter()); // 1000
System.out.println(foo.getAndIncrement()); // 1000
System.out.println(foo.getAndIncrement()); // 1001
System.out.println(foo.getAndIncrement()); // 1002
System.out.println(foo.resetCounter()); // 1000
```

In the second you access the static value. Statics can be referred to by to the class definition:

```
System.out.println(StaticFoo.resetCounter()); // 1000
System.out.println(StaticFoo.getAndIncrement()); // 1000
System.out.println(StaticFoo.getAndIncrement()); // 1001
System.out.println(StaticFoo.getAndIncrement()); // 1002
System.out.println(StaticFoo.resetCounter()); // 1000
```

In your example you are trying to increment the counter by doing `resetCounter()++`. This will not work for a separate reason entirely from being static or instance. Primitive values in Java (like ints, doubles, floats, etc) are pass by value, not pass by reference.

In a very simplistic sense, this means that once you return a primitive from a method like `resetCounter`, you are actually passing a copy of the value. You then incremented the copy, but the value associated with the class remains the same (because you incremented only the copy of the variable). You need to call the postfix operator `++` on the variable itself, not the value returned by the method. i.e. If I have

```
class StaticFoo {
    static int i = 1000;
    static int get() {
        return i;
    }
}

System.out.println(StaticFoo.get()++); // prints 1000 and adds 1. the copy is then destroyed
System.out.println(StaticFoo.get()++); // prints 1000 and adds 1, the copy is then destroyed
System.out.println(StaticFoo.i); // prints 1000
System.out.println(StaticFoo.i++); // prints 1000 and now a postfix is applied to the static variable
System.out.println(StaticFoo.i++); // prints 1001 and another postfix is applied to the static variable
System.out.println(StaticFoo.get()); // prints 1002 because two postifx operators were applied to StaticFoo.i.
```

Hope this helps you get started.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I'm blown away to be honest at how concise your answer is! keep doing what you're doing flakes. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I think that you are assigning value to a non compatible data type varaiable.
See my code for reference:

```
      public class Main
         {
         public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Hello World");
         int a = 10 + setCounter();
         System.out.println(a);
         }


        public static  int setCounter(){
        return 1000;
       }
       }
```

edit*

```
private String getTicketNumber(){
    ticketNumber = TICKET_PREFIX + resetCounter()++;
    return ticketNumber;

 public static void resetCounter(int counter){
        counter = 1000;

    }
```

i want to call this counter to increment it in another method